# NodeJS setTimeout/setInterval callback as a string

Tags: node.js, timer

as far as I know, NodeJS does not support callbacks passed by strings in setTimeout/setInterval functions. (e.g setTimeout("myfunc()", 100);)

Is there any implementation or any other solution to make this work? (e.g instead of calling callback, just eval it, etc..)
I'm just trying to load raw webpage which does exactly same thing so NodeJS just throws exceptions on that.

Comment: You want to fetch whole js from some web page and execute it in node? Doesn't sound like good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace native setTimeout with your one:

```
setTimeout = timeoutWrapper(setTimeout);

function timeoutWrapper(origSetTimeout) {
    var win = typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : window;

    function _setTimeout(fn) {
        var code;
        if(typeof fn === 'string') {
            code = fn
            fn = function wrapEval() {
                eval(code);
            };
        }
        arguments[0] = fn;
        origSetTimeout.apply(win, arguments);
    }

    return _setTimeout;
}
```

Test it:

```
setTimeout('console.log(123)', 100);
setTimeout(function(a,b,c) {
        console.log(a, b, c); 
    }, 100, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

Comment: Duh.. I did not thought about patching original function, I was way too much tired. Thanks, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

One way I can suggest is:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 eval("myfunc()")
}, 100);
```

**Edit** (to handle evalString passed as an argument)

```
function callMe(evalString){
   return function(){eval(evalString);}
}

setTimeout(callMe('myFunc()'), 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not quite what I expect.
There are response already like setTimeout('myfunc()', 0) so I have to somehow convert this to callback or eval passed string somehow.

Comment: hmm, gonna try that later and let you know the answer, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I still get unexpected results, does not do much but idea is nice tho.